# Update only one matrix element for iterative computation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix, A.  I also compute a value, *g*, as the maximum eigen value of A. I am trying to change the element A(3,3) = 0 for all values from zero to one in 0.10 increments and then update *g* for each of the values.  I'd like all of the other matrix elements to remain the same.

I thought a *for loop* would be the way to do this, but I do not know how to update only one element in a matrix without storing this update as one increasingly larger matrix.  If I call the element at A(3,3) = *p* (thereby creating a new matrix Atry) I am able (below) to get all of the values from 0 to 1 that I desired. I do not know how to update Atry to get all of the values of *g* that I desire. The state of the code now will give me the same value of *g* for all iterations, as expected, as I do not know how to to update Atry with the different values of *p* to then compute the values for *g*.

Any suggestions on how to do this or suggestions for jargon or phrases for me to web search would be appreciated.

```
A = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 0];  
g = max(eig(A));

% This below is what I attempted to achieve my solution
clear all  
p(1) = 0;
Atry = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 p];  
g(1) = max(eig(Atry));  

for i=1:100;  
    p(i+1) = p(i)+ 0.01;
    % this makes a one giant matrix, not many  
    %Atry(:,i+1) = Atry(:,i); 
    g(i+1) = max(eig(Atry));  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will also accomplish what you want to do:

```
A = @(x) [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 x];
p = 0:0.01:1;
g = arrayfun(@(x) eigs(A(x),1), p);
```

Breakdown:

- Define `A` as an anonymous function. This means that the command `A(x)` will return your matrix `A` with the `(3,3)` element equal to `x`.
- Define all steps you want to take in vector `p`
- Then "loop" through all elements in `p` by using `arrayfun` instead of an actual loop.

The function looped over by `arrayfun` is not `max(eig(A))` but `eigs(A,1)`, i.e., the `1` largest eigenvalue. The result will be the same, but the algorithm used by `eigs` is more suited for your type of problem -- instead of computing *all* eigenvalues and then only using the maximum one, you *only* compute the maximum one. Needless to say, this is much faster.

Comment: Rody, Thanks this was a very parsimonious solution to my question.  I am rather new to MATLAB and programming.  I will need to explore more about anonymous functions and arrayfun, however, I am not sure how I would have discovered them on my own.  Thanks for the help. I am sure I will ask more MATLAB questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First, you say 0.1 increments in the text of your question, but your code suggests you are actually interested in 0.01 increments? I'm going to operate under the assumption you mean 0.01 increments.

Now, with that out of the way, let me state what I believe you are after given my interpretation of your question. You want to iterate over the matrix A, where for each iteration you increase A(3, 3) by 0.01. Given that you want all values from 0 to 1, this implies 101 iterations. For each iteration, you want to calculate the maximum eigenvalue of A, and store all these eigenvalues in some vector (which I will call gVec). If this is correct, then I believe you just want the following:

```
% Specify the "Current" A
CurA = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 0];  
% Pre-allocate the values we want to iterate over for element (3, 3)
A33Vec = (0:0.01:1)';
% Pre-allocate a vector to store the maximum eigenvalues
gVec = NaN * ones(length(A33Vec), 1);
% Loop over A33Vec
for i = 1:1:length(A33Vec)
    % Obtain the version of A that we want for the current i
    CurA(3, 3) = A33Vec(i);
    % Obtain the maximum eigen value of the current A, and store in gVec
    gVec(i, 1) = max(eig(CurA));
end
```

**EDIT**: Probably best to paste this code into your matlab editor. The stack-overflow automatic text highlighting hasn't done it any favors :-)

**EDIT**: Go with Rody's solution (+1) - it is much better!

Comment: User Amro created a user script that will fix Matlab highlighting on SE in your browser, see the [Matlab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/info). In firefox, install with Greasemonkey. Chrome has native support for it.

Comment: Nice. Worked perfectly. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Colin T Bowers - This is definitely the route I was envisioning if I was able to fully envision the end script.  While Rody's code is more parsimonious I imagine that I will use the help you provided to attempt new solutions in the future as it is more akin to my current skill set.  Thank you.

Comment: Did you know `NaN(length(A33vec),1)` also works? In Matlab, `NaN` is a matrix-generating command. The command `NaN` by itself is interpreted as `NaN(1,1)`. Same holds for `inf`, `true`, `false`, `ones`, `zeros`, `rand`, and a few more.

Comment: I did not. That is a neat trick, thanks. I'll definitely use it as I am a big fan of pre-initializing using NaN rather than zeros or ones.